# Nodejs Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

I'm receiving the above error at this line `set active(val)` of the following code:

middleware.js

```
class middleware {

    constructor(){
        this.active = false;
    };

    set active(val) {
        this.active = val;
    };

    get active(){
        return this.active;
    };

}

module.exports = middleware
```

routes.js

```
const middleware = require('../middleware')

router.get("/start", passport.authenticate('jwt', { failureRedirect: '/login' }), (req, res) => {

    var mw = new middleware()
    mw.active = true;

}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your `active` property is an *accessor property*, and you're assigning to it in its own setter. That invokes the setter again, which invokes the setter again, etc.

If you want `active` to be an accessor property, you need to store the value elsewhere. These days, you can use a private field in modern versions of Node.js:

```
class middleware {
    #active = false;

    constructor(){
    }

    set active(val) {
        this.#active = val;
    }

    get active(){
        return this.#active;
    }
}
```

Or just another property:

```
class middleware {
    constructor(){
        this._active = false;
    }

    set active(val) {
        this._active = val;
    }

    get active(){
        return this._active;
    }
}
```

Or make `active` a data property:

```
class middleware {
    constructor(){
        this.active = false;
    }
}
```

---

Side note: Method definitions in `class` bodies don't have `;` after them. (A `;` is tolerated there by the language grammar, but it's not supposed to be there.)